# Fixed object to the right of an NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, nswindow

I have created an `NSView` on an `NSWindow`. I'm trying to "dock" the view to the right side of the window, so that when I scale the window the view will always stay on the right side.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Add an observer for the `NSWindowDidResizeNotification` notification of your parent window and adjust your child window's frame accordingly.

Comment: Correct, but you're assuming that the questioner has done something he might not know about. @Jonah Siegle: You need to put the view into a child window. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/addChildWindow:ordered:

Comment: I somehow thought that he already had a child window, but now that I read the question again, it seems to me that it's a simple case of setting an autoresizing mask.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
[myView setAutoResizingMask: NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMaxYMargin];
```

That should keep the view in the upper right corner of its superview. If you want the entire right side, use `NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewHeightSizeable | NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewMaxYMargin` instead. It will be anchored to the right side and the top and bottom will resize with the superview. Now just place it on the right spot and it should stay there.

Comment: You've interpreted the question as being how to keep the view at the right edge or a right corner inside the window, but the question sounds to me like the questioner wants the view to be outside the window, hanging off the right edge. (Also, I think you have autoresizing masks backwards. The set bits identify which portions are resizable, not which portions are fixed; they indicate springs, not struts. So, for your example, `MaxX | MaxY` = pinned to the lower-left, not the upper-right.)

Comment: Yes, that is how I interpreted it, since he wrote the NSView is ON the NSWindow. And you're right about the NSViewXXX bits. I am used to anchors, and these are exactly the opposite.